# Applying a function to every possible combination of 2 keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very big dictionary that has a word as a key and a vector as value, something like this

```
groceries = {'apples': array([1,2,1],dtype=float32),
             'bananas': array([1,3,4],dtype=float32),
             'potatoes': array([1,4,4],dtype=float32)}
```

Each vector is a representation of score for the grocery shop manager. I would like to find score for each possible combination of 2 keys. In this case a score for 'apples+bananas', score for 'bananas+potatoes', and score for 'apples+potatoes'.

So, I need to calculate all the possible sums of every key value with every other key value.
I have a function that takes 2 variables:

```
def summing(u, v):
    return u+v
```

This function takes variables and sums their values, so the sum for 'apples+bananas' should be [2,5,5]

What would be a scaleable way to do it?
I am trying to work with itertools, but I haven't used it before and it became very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sums = {key_combo: sum(groceries[k] for k in key_combo) for key_combo in itertools.combinations(groceries, 2)}
```

Explanation: `itertools.combinations` creates all combinations. The dictionary comprehension sums the values for each combination and assigns the results to a dictionary keyed with the combinations. Result is:

```
sums
{('apples', 'bananas'): array([2., 5., 5.], dtype=float32),
 ('apples', 'potatoes'): array([2., 6., 5.], dtype=float32),
 ('bananas', 'potatoes'): array([2., 7., 8.], dtype=float32)}
```

The function `summing` is not really necessary, as the numpy arrays know very well how to sum themselves.

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked! :)  I would still prefer using a function as I might need to use other operations such as calculating a cosine of the vectors, or do divisions on the same data

Comment: You can call your function in the dict comprehension as follows: `sums = {key_combo: summing(groceries[key_combo[0]], groceries[key_combo[1]]) for key_combo in itertools.combinations(groceries, 2)}`